# Typeahead displaying object values

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to make suggestions on products. I want to display all the details like protein, carbs, fat on the website. The problem is that i can`t display these details in Html:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="product.name for product in products | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10">
<p>selected item has : {{ selected.protein }} protein</p>
<p>selected item has : {{ selected.fat }} fat</p>
<p>selected item has : {{ selected.carbs }} carbs</p>
```

This is an example of how a single product looks like:

```
{ 
  "id": 2, 
  "name": "soup", 
  "protein": 1.12, 
  "fat": 1.16, 
  "carbs": 8.45, 
  "cholesterol": 0,
  "type": "soup"
}
```

If i try using this instead:

```
uib-typeahead="product for product in products | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"
```

The input`s value will be [object Object] but you will be able to display all the details. This way the ng-model **selected** will return a json of the product.

**EDIT:** https://codepen.io/daniss/pen/zqbzGj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by doing:

```
uib-typeahead="product as product.name for product in products | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to add ui.bootstrap in angualar module. Here is the code

```
// setup app and pass ui.bootstrap as dep
var myApp = angular.module("angularTypeahead", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

// setup controller and pass data source
myApp.controller("TypeaheadCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.selected = undefined;

    $scope.products = [{"name": "Prabhaker"},{"name": "Prabhash"},{"name": "Prakash"}];

});

<input name="products" id="products" type="text" placeholder="enter a product" ng-model="selected" typeahead="product.name for product in products | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

code pen: http://codepen.io/Prabhaker/pen/EKMmVZ

Comment: The ui.bootstrap is working fine for me since I already have this. I just want to display more than 2 values of json data. Let me update the code.